# Glassfish connection pool don't work after restart server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3, connection-pooling

**QUESTION CHANGED**

I have a connection pool in Glassfish 3.1 to connect to SqlServer 2008 Express, this pool works fine, but when Glassfish is restarted, the connection pool can't ping and stops working. To work again, I go to pool configuration->aditional properties and change host name (ex. localhost to 127.0.0.1), as you can see in this screen.[image: aditional properties]

I've noticed this problem just happens when my application is deployed before server restart... If my application isn't deployed and I restart server, no problem happens when I try to ping the pool. Looking at log file, I can see these warnings at deployment:

```
[#|2012-06-22T17:24:48.979-0300|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Record begin marker is not a proper value so using default.|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:24:48.979-0300|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Record end marker is not a proper value so using default.|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:24:48.979-0300|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Log Format field separator is not a character so using default.|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:20.080-0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/hudson/projetos/ERP-HM/modulos-web/erp-web/target/erp-web-0.1.0/WEB-INF/lib/persistencia-erp-0.1.0.jar_erpPU.ejb_or_metadata|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|You have specified multiple ids for the entity class [com.hrgi.persistencia.erp.entidades.Composicao] without specifying an @IdClass. By doing this you may lose the ability to find by identity, distributed cache support etc. Note: You may however use entity manager find operations by passing a list of primary key fields. Else, you will have to use JPQL queries to read your entities. For other id options see @PrimaryKey.|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:41.769-0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Invalid JavaBean property 'armazenador' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void com.hrgi.persistencia.nfe.controladores.ControladorArmazenamentoEmitenteNFe.setArmazenador(com.hrgi.persistencia.nfe.dao.interfaces.IEmitenteDao)]: [public void com.hrgi.persistencia.controladores.ControladorArmazenamento.setArmazenador(com.hrgi.persistencia.dao.IArmazenadorDao)]|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:49.734-0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/hudson/projetos/ERP-HM/modulos-web/erp-web/target/erp-web-0.1.0/WEB-INF/lib/persistencia-erp-0.1.0.jar_erpPU.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@2ed0005e].|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:49.737-0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/hudson/projetos/ERP-HM/modulos-web/erp-web/target/erp-web-0.1.0/WEB-INF/lib/persistencia-erp-0.1.0.jar_erpPU.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@2ed0005e] from index [0] |#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:49.740-0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/hudson/projetos/ERP-HM/modulos-web/erp-web/target/erp-web-0.1.0/WEB-INF/lib/persistencia-erp-0.1.0.jar_erpPU.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@e40e825] from index [1] |#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:52.457-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLER' found.|#]
[#|2012-06-22T17:25:52.474-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_TEMPLATE_RESOURCE' found, using default value 'META-INF/rsc/myfaces-dev-error.xml'.|#]
```

I supressed an javax.mail.MessagingException, because it happens when no password is setted to connect to mail server...

Is there something wrong in my application that is causing this problem??

Comment: Do I read your question right: The pool configuration changes during server restart, from 127.0.0.1 to localhost?

Comment: No. The configuration doesn't change after restart, pool simply doesn't works with the host. So I mannually change pool configuration from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, and it works...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it ;-) Why don't you use localhost? How is your connection pool configured? Does it get deployed together with your application or did you configure it manually?

Comment: The pool is configured manually, as you can see in picture. I see you didn't understand... So think this way, the connection is running wonderfully and for some reason I need to restart glassfish server. After the restart connection pool does not work. All the configurations are the same before server restart... So I enter in pool configuration and just change from localhost to 127.0.0.1 or change from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and works again. If the server is restarted again, I need to change host again...

Comment: You should check your domain.xml and compare the connection pool settings before and after the restart. Are there any differences?

Comment: I've updated question with new informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was in jndi dataSource...
I simply removed jndi dataSource and used local datasource in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Mmhh thats extrange...

I would first check the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Make sure the mapping of localhost is not corrupted...

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Either way, this seems to be an issue of name resolution, either with the hosts file or the DNS server.

Could you check those and give more info if any more available ??

Comment: The hosts file is the same you mentioned and dns server is configured correctly. Perhaps is a glassfish problem...